# How to push built image from 1 Nexus repository to another?

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I'm a newbee to Nexus. Having recently incorporated git into our development team, I'm trying to work on a solution to first create a build image of the app (via maven) from a cloned GIT repo, then distributing it to the development environment and then to a remotely stored Nexus repo [DEV].

I'm working with 3 target environments and 3 respective Nexus repo's [ Dev, QA-Test and Prod ]. I want to move these built images from 1 Nexus repo to another [from DEV to QA-TEST, from QA-TEST to PROD].

What I'm curious about is that is there a way within Nexus itself to copy the built image from 1 nexus repo to another instead of having it pulled down to a local file system working directory and then pushing it up (promoting it) to another repository?

Answer (score 1):

Nexus Professional includes the Staging Suite that is designed to do exactly that. Read more about it [staging chapter](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) of the book Repository Management with Nexus and try it out with the [eval version](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/free-trial).

Comment: Thanks Manferd. The problem is that we don't use Nexus Pro in my workplace. Just the base version. Is this still possible to do in the Non-Pro version of nexus?

Comment: The problem is that we don't use Nexus Pro in my workplace. Just the base version. Is this still possible to do in the Non-Pro version of nexus?
Maybe I need to change the approach. I'm able to build a war file and push it to a nexus snapshot repository. What I need to figure out is how to extract it from the snapshot repo and then scp it the war to the target destination server/path and stop/start tomcat. Once its ready for QA, I need to extract it from the snapshot repo, push into the release repo extract it again from the snapshot repo and then push it out to the target. Any thoughts?

Comment: The deployment can be done by picking up the war from the repo with your tool of choice via http/https or using the Nexus REST api if you like.

Comment: The release process on the other hand could be emulated by cutting full releases with a version classifier like 1.0.0-RC1 and so on. This is all possible with the OS version. Staging just makes it much smoother and has rule execution and notifications as part of it as well so it is MUCH more powerful.